# GeoPDF Library for .NET or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, .net, pdf

Anyone know of any open source .NET or Javascript libraries for creating GeoPDFs?

I know of [QuickPDFLibrary](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/blog/tag/geopdf/), but i'm preferably looking for something open source.

I want to programmatically generate some GeoPDFs.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, PDF is proprietary and as such any reverse engineering would be infringement. My information indicates that adobe has stopped all geopdf dev, and terrago is the sole proprietor of patent now. OGC has developed an open-source geopdf specification but that is only to try to steer developers toward what they want. Discussion is open and would be beneficial for this community to understand even better than I do. So, if anyone else can enlighten us - submit an answer at least.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Brad, i'm under the same understanding.